# How to display multiple jsp pages using web view in my single android application?

Tags: android

Hi
How to display multiple jsp pages using web view in my single android application?
I want to display 6 different web pages(jsp pages) in my single android application. How can I do that using WebView?

Here is my code::

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {         
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);       
    this.getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);   
    setContentView(R.layout.main);               
    WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);    
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);      
    webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {    
        public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {   
            activity.setTitle("Loading...");  
            activity.setProgress(progress * 100);          
                if(progress == 100) activity.setTitle(R.string.app_name);   
        }           
    });          
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {   
        @Override             
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {      
            // Handle the error            
        }                 
        @Override        
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {    
            view.loadUrl(url);        
            return true;             
        }         
    });       

    webView.loadUrl("http://ipAddress/HelloJSP/welcome.jsp");  

    webView.loadUrl("http://ipAddress:8080/HelloJSP/helloo.jsp"); 
}
```

Regards,
Sneha

Comment: @Sneha Have you tried anything?

Comment: yeah I have tried to load 2 different URLs : webView.loadUrl(http://ipAddress:8080/HelloJSP/welcome.jsp"); webView.loadUrl(http://ipAddress:8080/HelloJSP/hello.jsp"); and it displays only the second page!

Comment: Did you have any luck on this Sneha? I am stuck as well =(

Comment: what problem were you facing ? because at my end I am not able to load even a single JSP that contains 'scriptlet'.